# android progressbar white circle

Tags: android, progress

Hi im invoking a simple progress bar in android with the following code

```
MyDialog = ProgressDialog.show(attraction_more_info.this, " " , 
                               " Loading. Please wait ... ", true);
```

The thing is when it comes up there is a small white circle with a white triangle in it above the spinning icon.  How do i get rid of this so it is only the spinning circle and the text.

it looks like the following image although myne does not say the "indeterminate" part.

[image]
<sub>(source: [lytsing.org](http://blog.lytsing.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/progressbar_indeterminate.jpg))</sub>

Probably something simple to get rid of it.

Thanks

Comment: pass null in title if you donot want to use

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space in between the "" after attraction_more_info.this. It's the title. You can enter anything within the double quotes but its optional. E.g. Retrieving Information

From this:

`MyDialog = ProgressDialog.show(attraction_more_info.this, " " , 
                               " Loading. Please wait ... ", true);`

Into this:

`MyDialog = ProgressDialog.show(attraction_more_info.this, "" , 
                               " Loading. Please wait ... ", true);`

Answer (score 0):

Go for this instead,

```
MyDialog = ProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
```

This will provide you with your expected result.